# how to insert a string to new line to a file in azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

New to windows environment,i have requirement to insert a string to a yaml file using azure pipeline

string : `Version: 7368684846gdvjdgjv`

file name: test.txt

file content:

```
    test:
      test1: one
      test2: two
      key: value
```

below is the step i have used in pipeline

`- script: 'echo ^ Version: 7368684846gdvjdgjv >> test.txt'` and tried different options as below mentioned

`- script: 'echo. & echo Version: 7368684846gdvjdgjv >> test.txt'`

after this the file content looks like this

```
    test:
      test1: one
      test2: two
      key: value Version: 7368684846gdvjdgjv
```

but expected is

```
    test:
      test1: one
      test2: two
      key: value 
      Version: 7368684846gdvjdgjv
```

is there any option to achieve this functionality.

Note:- agent is windows machine

Comment: Not get your latest information, is Krzysztof Madej's workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try with `powershell-yaml` [module](https://github.com/cloudbase/powershell-yaml):

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: JA
    steps:
    - pwsh: Install-Module powershell-yaml -Force
    - pwsh: |
        $content = Get-Content -Path stackoverflow\30-yaml\test.yaml -Raw

        $obj = ConvertFrom-Yaml $content

        $obj.Item('test').Add('Version', '7368684846gdvjdgjv')

        $newContent = ConvertTo-Yaml $obj

        $newContent

        Set-Content -Path stackoverflow\30-yaml\test.yaml -Value $newContent
        Set-Content -Path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\test.yaml -Value $newContent

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      artifact: someArtifact
```

I got this result:

```yaml
test:
  Version: 7368684846gdvjdgjv
  test1: one
  test2: two
```